# Definition of a index variable in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am very new to Java and am currently learning about arrays. Our homework this week is to

"Write a program that declares an array "alpha" of 50 elements of type "double". Initialize the array so that the first 25 elements are equal to the square of the index variable and the last 25 elements are equal to three times the index variable"

My question is this. Is the value in the element at an index position considered the index variable. For example if alpha[2] = 3 would 3 be the index variable, and in reading the assignment I would then square 3.

The other thought that I would have is that I have to square the index number [0],[1],[2]...

Thank you for any input, and I apologize if this is in the wrong area.

---

Thank you for the input so far. What I am trying to get to is what exactly is an "Index Variable"

---

Here is what I did

```
// Import various packages to be used in the program
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class module5
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // Declare an array called alpha with 50 pre-defined elements
        double []alpha = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50};

        // Process the first 25 elements
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            // Square the first 25 elements
            alpha[i] = Math.pow(alpha[i], 2);         
        }

        // Process the second set of 25
        for (int i = 25; i >= 25 && i < 50; i++) {
            // Multiply by 3
            alpha[i] = alpha[i] * 3;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; ++i) {
            System.out.print(alpha[i]);

            if (i % 10 == 9) {
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html - first link in google regarding "array index java"

Comment: `if alpha[2] = 3 would 3 be the index variable`  no , 3 would be value of element at index 2.

Comment: Expecting a little more clarity in your question

Comment: `int i = 2; alpha[i] = 3;` -- i is the index variable, 2 is the index position, 3 is the value at index i.

Comment: I think your professor is probably looking for alpha[0] = 0, alpha[1] = 1, alpha[2] = 4, alpha[3] = 9...up until index 24.  Then 25 through 49 are three times the index so alpha[25] = 75, etc....

Comment: *Index variable:* The variable used to index the array. The variable `i` would be an index variable in the expression `arr[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

No. In `alpha[2] = 3` `2` is the index variable, and `3` is the ***value*** being indexed.  *The other thought that I would have is that I have to square the index number [0],[1],[2]* Correct.

```
alpha[0] = 0 * 0;
alpha[1] = 1 * 1;
alpha[2] = 2 * 2;
// ...
alpha[25] = 3 * 25;
// ...
alpha[49] = 3 * 49;
```

You are expected (I think) to use a loop with a *conditional* (but you might also use two separate loops with different initial and terminal conditions) to do these assignments.

You are dealing with `int`(s), so use an `int[]`. Something like,

```
int[] alpha = new int[50];
```

Then you might use a single `for` loop like,

```
for (int index = 0; index < alpha.length; index++) {
    if (index < 25) {
        alpha[index] = index * index;
    } else {
        alpha[index] = index * 3;
    }
}
```

**or** two loops like

```
for (int index = 0; index < 25; index++) {
    alpha[index] = index * index;
}
for (int index = 25; index < alpha.length; index++) {
    alpha[index] = 3 * index;
}
```

**or** using a ternary (conditional operator `? :`) and a loop like

```
for (int index = 0; index < alpha.length; index++) {
    alpha[index] = index * ((index < 25) ? index : 3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did design a couple different loops, but think I went the wrong direction.

Comment: Edit your question to include your attempt, and I'll try and help you with fixing that.

Comment: Thanks for the input and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The index of an array element is the number in the brackets, [].
In the example, alpha[2] = 3, 2 is the index and 3 is the variable stored at index 2.

Also remember that for arrays, index 2 means that it is the third position in the array because the first index is position 0.

For this exercise, you would declare an index variable, i, and iterate through the array such that alpha[0] = 0, alpha[1] = 1, alpha[2] = 4, ... alpha[i] = i*i

Comment: ...only up to 24. 25-49 need 3*index.

Comment: Yeah, i such that i < 25, then either a different for loop for 25-49 or a condition in the for loop.